# how can I foreach my array inside?

Tags: php

I want to foreach my array inside my array, but when I try to foreach again with my neasted array then show me an error like  `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` , So how can I foreach it?

my output looks like this

```
low stock
Array
(
    [0] => 4170
    [1] => 4171
)
1
low stock
1500584174
```

my funtion

```
 public function tests()
    {
        $array = $this->sale->get_all_cart($this->session->carrito);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $product_id[] = $value['id'];
        }

        $entryData = array(
            'message' => 'low stock',
            'product_id'    =>  $product_id,
            'user_id'  => 1,
            'type'     => 'low stock',
            'timestamp' => time()
        );

        foreach ($entryData as $key => $value) {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($value);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: before using foreach, try to check if the variable is array and not empty by adding condition if(is_array($variable) && count($variable)>0){ foreach() }

Comment: Which foreach is failing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one `if` block inside the outer `foreach` loop and check whether `$key` is `product_id` or not, and furthermore whether `$value` is an array or not. Then only loop through further using another `foreach` loop.

So your second `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
// your code
foreach ($entryData as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'product_id' && is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            echo $k . " => " . $v . '<br />';
        }
    }else{
        echo $key . " => " . $value . '<br />';
    }
}
```